# For Loop at Python

Tags: python, for-loop

My goal is to create a for-loop code that will return an output like the following:

```
list(indicator.values())[0],
list(indicator.values())[1],
list(indicator.values())[2],
list(indicator.values())[3],
...
...
list(indicator.values())[98],
list(indicator.values())[99],
```

However when I run the code below, I receive an error message 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'. How can I fix this so I can get the intended result?

```
x = 100
for item in x:
    list(indicator.values())[item]
```

Comment: ```for item in range(x)```. But the style of this code is worrisome at least.

Comment: Possible duplicat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523563/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
x = 100
for item in range(x):
    print(list(indicator.values())[item])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `range()` with `for` to iterate it from 0 to 100. For example:

```
for i in range(100):
    print i
# prints number from 1 to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

read this [document](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

and try this code

```
x = range(0,100)

for item in x:
    list(indicator.values())[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

For -- in -- is python's way of iterating (going through) something iterable (something that can be gone through). For example a list and a dictionary are iterable. The range function creates **a list** with given parameters, making an integer (which is not itself iterable) iterable.