# Pandas convert Series of strings to Series of lists of strings (of size 1) for encoding

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I know the title is confusing, but let me explain. I'm trying to prepare Series' for a `sklearn.MultiLableBinarizer`, with each string being a separate user id I want to one-hot-encode. Erroneously, it is iterating over each individual character of the string. Doing `series.apply(list)` does the same thing, splitting each string into its individual characters. If the series goes like:

```
0 '3436803478'
1 '1230782212'
2 '7320482099'
...
```

Then I want the output to be

```
0 ['3436803478']
1 ['1230782212']
2 ['7320482099']
...
```

Instead of

```
0 ['3','4','3','6','8','0','3','4','7','8']
1 ['1','2','3','0','7','8','2','2','1','2']
2 ['7','3','2','0','4','8','2','0','9','9']
...
```

If I were working with a single value, I would just do `ids = [[s] for s in values]`, but since we're working with Series and `apply()`, I need something like a function name, but for `[]`. `list()` doesn't work, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523563/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable)

Note: The strings actually start as integers, but I can get around that with `.apply(str)`

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I explained in the first paragraph that `s.apply(list)` splits into individual characters, which I don't want.

Comment: can you show up your actual data frame structure, though you got the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining `s.apply(lambda x: [x])` works perfectly.