# Convert pandas series of strings to a series of lists

Tags: python, pandas

For iinstance I have a dataframe as below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":['AM RLC, F C', 'AM/F C', 'DM','D C']})

    |col
-------------------|
0   |"AM RLC, F C" |
1   |"AM/F C"      |
2   |"DM"          |
3   |"D C"         |
```

My expected output is as following

```
    |col
----|-----------------------|
 0  |["AM", "RLC", "F", "C"]|
 1  |["AM", "F", "C"]       |
 2  |["DM" ]                |
 3  |["D", "C"]             |
```

",", "/" and "space" should be treated as delimiter,

The answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675820/pandas-convert-series-of-strings-to-series-of-lists-of-strings-of-size-1-for-e) do not answer my queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) or [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split('[\s,/]+')

# or
df['col'] = df['col'].str.findall('\w+')
```

Output:

```
               col
0  [AM, RLC, F, C]
1       [AM, F, C]
2             [DM]
3           [D, C]
```

Regex:

```
[\s,/]+  # at least one of space/comma/slash with optional repeats

\w+      # one or more word characters
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
df["col"].apply(lambda x:x.replace(",","").replace("/"," ").split(" "))
```

Answer (score 2):

An one-liner that finds any punctuation in your string and replaces it with empty space. Then you can split the string and get a clean list:

```
import string

df['col'].str.replace(f'[{string.punctuation}]', ' ', regex=True).str.split().to_frame()
```

Comment: This won't work as you showed it, there are many mistakes, f-string is incorrect, you need to craft and use a regex, and replace with a space. For instance: `df['col'].str.replace(f'[{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]+', ' ', regex=True).str.split()`

Comment: You are right, thanks for your vigilance. I edited my original answer and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a function on rows of `col` column to filter its content. In this case the function is written in lambda form.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"col":['AM RLC, F C', 'AM/F C', 'DM','D C']})

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: str(re.findall(r"[\w']+", x)))

print(df.head())
```

output:

```
                       col
0  ['AM', 'RLC', 'F', 'C']
1         ['AM', 'F', 'C']
2                   ['DM']
3               ['D', 'C']
```