# Python Web Scraping Error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, int, typeerror

I have been trying to modify a program I found that gives you three random top news headlines. Heres the code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import random

news_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss"
Client=urlopen(news_url)
xml_page=Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page=soup(xml_page,"xml")
news_list=soup_page.findAll("item")
# Print news title, url and publish date
news_list = random.choice(news_list)
for news_list in range(3):
    for news in news_list:
        print(news.title.text)
        print(news.link.text)
        print(news.pubDate.text)
        print("-"*60)
```

And heres the error I get with the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newsstuff.py", line 16, in <module>
    for news in news_list:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I hope someone can help thanks!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523563/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.choice` returns only one element. Then, you have `for news_list in range(3)` , so `news_list` here is just an integer. You want `random.choices` (note the 's')  with an argument of 3, and to iterate over those:

```
news_list = random.choices(news_list, k=3)
for news in news_list:
    print(news.title.text)
    print(news.link.text)
    print(news.pubDate.text)
    print("-"*60)
```

Answer (score -1):

when you do:

```
news_list = random.choice(news_list)
```

random.choice function return a single element of an array, list, or sequence. In this case an element on news_list.
After this line the new value of news_list is a single element, checking the error that you're getting, is an int variable, which isn't iterable through a for.